# Auto Pointer in C++ (auto_ptr)

Tags: c++, pointers, auto-ptr

I am trying to figure out what this piece of code prints but I couldn't output it for some reason, it gave me an error: "1 [main] Q1c 5752 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to Q1c.exe.stackdump".

```
double *dp=new double(1.2);
auto_ptr <double> autodp1(dp);
auto_ptr <double> autodp2=autodp1;
cout<<*autodp1<<endl;
```

I just want to know what it will print, if it even prints.

Notice: this question was in past exam paper, just for revision.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is very difficult to use, let alone to use correctly. Unless you're a C++ expert, just don't use it.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. It could even print `"FAIL!"`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am not using it, it is just a question that I want to know the answer for.

Comment: Was answering "UB" allowed and expected?

Comment: Just for reference, `auto_ptr` has officially been deprecated in C++11 and beyond instead use `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `*autodp1` is effectively a dereferencing of a null pointer. Therefore the code exhibits undefined behavior.

You first construct `autodp1` to point to the newly allocated `double`. But then the constructor of `autodp2` takes the owned memory for itself and sets `autodp1` to null.

Comment: Alright then, I guess that's the answer for this question.
Thank you @JurajBlaho

Comment: Then please mark it as such so Juraj gets proper credit for it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, Done.

Answer (score 1):

That's becouse the operator assignement of auto_ptr takes's the ownership (move) the pointer

Take a read on Wiki, it's quite good general explanation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

"The copy constructor and assignment operators of std::auto_ptr do not actually copy the stored pointer. Instead, they transfer it, leaving the previous std::auto_ptr object empty. This was one way to implement strict ownership, so that only one auto_ptr object could own the pointer at any given time. This means that auto_ptr should not be used where copy semantics are needed."